# Unable to get output of Switch condition in Powershell. Use case is to simply check keyword "G-" in dir containing files with extension- *.bo, *.mo

Tags: powershell

May be I am making a silly mistake that I am not able to identify. I am new to Powershell and using Switch first time. I need your help to get this switch case working.

Unable to get output of below Switch condition in Powershell. Use case is to simply check for the keyword "G-" in a directory containing several text but non .txt files with extension- *.bo, *.mo
Here is my code:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem $all* -Include *.mo, *.bo, *.tf -Recurse 

foreach ($folder in $file) { 
    if (Select-String -List -Pattern G- -Path $folder -CaseSensitive) {
        $GL1 = 'D:\Data\Policy\BaseDir\GlobalPolicy\G-BaseAgentConfiguration\Latest' 
        $GL2 = 'D:\Data\Policy\BaseDir\GlobalPolicy\G-BaseEventSetup\Latest' 
        $GL3 = 'D:\Data\Policy\BaseDir\GlobalPolicy\G-SupportTools\Latest' 
        $timestamp3 = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss 
        $Old = "$G1$timestamp3" 
        
        switch ('$folder') {
            'G-BaseAgentConfiguration' { 
                Write-Info("Within 'G-' if Block[$folder]") 
                if (!(Test-Path $G1)) 
                # if (!(Test-Path $log_file_path)) { 
                    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $G1 | 
                        Out-Null Write-Info("Latest directory [$G1] within Global Policy directory [$gp1] created") 
                    Copy-Item -Path $folder.fullname -Destination "$G1" 
                    Write-Info("First ever Policy backup [$folder] is stored to [$G1] within Global Policy directory [$gp1]") 
                } 
                else { 
                    Write-Info("Latest directory [$G1] within Global Policy directory [$gp1] already exists") 
                    $LatestContents = Get-ChildItem -Path $G1 -Name 
                    Write-Info("Latest Directory already contains [$LatestContents]")

                    #Creation of foder with Latest timestamp to move the Backup from Latest to Different Directory. 
                    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Old | 
                        Out-Null Write-Info("Directory [$Old] within Global Policy directory [$gp1] created to move Old Backup") 
                    Get-ChildItem -Path "$G1" -Recurse | 
                        Move-Item -Destination "$Old" 
                    Write-Info("Existing Policy Backup [$G1] Moved from [$G1] to $Old") 
                    $LatestContents1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $Old -Name 
                    Write-Info("Latest Directory contains [$LatestContents1]") 
                    Write-Info(Invoke-Expression [$LatestContents])Dir 
                     
                    #Time to Copy the Latest Policy Backup 
                    Copy-Item -Path $folder.fullname -Destination "$G1" 
                    Write-Info("Latest Policy backup [$folder] is stored to [$G1] within Global Policy directory [$gp1]") 
                }
            }

            default {
                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

====================================================================================================

```
*Not even able to print the first statement within switch(Just to test if the control even goes inside Switch):
Write-Info("Within 'G-' if Block[$folder]")
But if I place it outside switch and immediately after the if opening brace, it works properly and also prints the output with expected 3 Global Policy finding files. **
```

Comment: Try changing `switch ('$folder') {` to `switch ($folder.Name) {`

Comment: You're also missing a bracket: `if (!(Test-Path $G1))  {`

Comment: Hi Danial.
Thank you so much for your reply. I did make the changes as suggested (indeed the code was whit2021-06-01T09:50:28: []: INFO:  D:\Data\Policy\BaseDir\All\2021-06-01_09-49-24\aeu1daaa001aad.ad003.siemens.net_Policies.mo
2021-06-01T09:50:28: []: INFO:  D:\Data\Policy\BaseDir\All\2021-06-01_09-49-27\aeu1daaa001aad.ad003.siemens.net_Policies.mo
2021-06-01T09:50:28: []: INFO:  D:\Data\Policy\BaseDir\All\2021-06-01_09-50-09\aeu1daaa001aad.ad003.siemens.net_Policies.mo
out quotes before):
switch ($folder.Name)/switch ($folder.fullname)
Unfortunately it has still not helped.

Comment: For the if brace, that was a typo while copying the code here. You can ignore that as it was corrected already.